# Returning binomal as a tuple

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I want to save the results of my function binomal_aux to a tuple but I don't have an idea how to, here is my code I have right now.

```
def binomal (n):    
    i=0
    for i in range(n):
        binomal_aux(n,i) #want this to be in a tuple so, binomal (2) = (1,2,1)
    return

def binomal_aux (n,k):
    if (k==0):
        return 1
    elif (n==k):
        return 1
    else:
        return (binomal_aux(n-1,k) + binomal_aux(n-1,k-1))
```

Comment: Note: it's spelled binomial, not binomal.

Comment: You don't need to declare/define `i` before the for loop, nor do you need the `return` at the end of your function.

Comment: Okay, one more. your if/elif can be replaced by simply: `if k==0 or k==n:`, or even `if k in (0, n):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `binomal` function, just make the tuple you want to return.

```
def binomal(n):
  return tuple(binomal_aux(n, i) for i in range(n+1))
```

Note also that the correct spelling is `binom`*i*`al`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def binomal (n):    
    return tuple(binomal_aux(n,i) for i in range(n+1))
```

Comment: changed  return tuple(binomal_aux(n,i) for i in range(n+1))
and works perfectly thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way:

```
def binomal(n): 
    from itertools import combinations
    return tuple(len(list(combinations(range(n), r=t))) for t in range(n + 1))
```